Is there a grammatical framework that gets rid of an intermediate projection X'?
In formal grammars inspired by the generativist tradition, an intermediate projection X' of head X is not considered a phrase. Only the maximal projection is. That's for structural completeness.
Is there a grammatical framework that gets rid of an intermediate projection X' (and perhaps treats X' also as a phrase)?

Before the advent of X-bar Theory, most phrase structure syntax treated at least some (what would later become known as) X' units as phrases. This is particularly true of the finite VP string, e.g. visited Mary in Max visited Mary. That string was designated simply a VP.
